# WMV decoder inconsistent sample timestamp

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I am running into a weird issue. I have a pipeline with a custom renderer written in-house. The pipeline is built with IMFMediaSession and the rendere user the Media Session presentation clock in order to schedule samples. This is all good. I am testing the pipeline with various videos. I have a WMV video which acts weird.

The issue happens during seeking. If MediaSession->Start is called with any time besides '0', the first sample received is usually way ahead of the clock. For example, the video is 163 seconds. Passing 138x10^7 nano-seconds to the start method, sets the clock at 138 seconds. However the first frame I get has the timestamp of 162. Another example is starting at 38 seconds, results in frames starting at 78. This is around 30 seconds difference.

I tested this with TopoEdit.exe (both installed and source code from the SDK) and it is consistent. In case of TopoEdit, some of the seeks takes around 8-10 seconds for the drawing to start while the clock is progressing.

I did not see this happening with .mov or mp4 files. Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Update: .mov files also give me frames from the range of 1 to 5 seconds ahead of the clock

Comment: It sounds like MediaSession->Start seeks to the first keyframe of the video: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757001(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You can also check and try to use this method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448055(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @VuVirt Thanks for the links. It seems this is the issue. I am running Win 10 and querying the scrubbing service on WMV does not return anything. My guess is that tools such as VLC player and Media Player create indices of the key frames for easier seeking.